# When shall use setAutoCommit(true) in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I've searched about the difference between `getConnection().commit()` (1) vs `getConnection().setAutoCommit(true)` (2). But most of case just describe that (1) is default method and rarely to use it instead of (2) or both method are "different purposes" and same result.
I use the example on Oracle docs
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#commit_transactions):

```
 public void updateCoffeeSales(HashMap<String, Integer> salesForWeek)
        throws SQLException {

        PreparedStatement updateSales = null;
        PreparedStatement updateTotal = null;

        String updateString =
            "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
            "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";

        String updateStatement =
            "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
            "set TOTAL = TOTAL + ? " +
            "where COF_NAME = ?";

        try {
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
            updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : salesForWeek.entrySet()) {
                updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
                updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey());
                updateSales.executeUpdate();
                updateTotal.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
                updateTotal.setString(2, e.getKey());
                updateTotal.executeUpdate();
                con.commit();
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e ) {
            JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                    con.rollback();
                } catch(SQLException excep) {
                    JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(excep);
                }
            }
        } 
        finally {
            if (updateSales != null) {
                updateSales.close();
            }
            if (updateTotal != null) {
                updateTotal.close();
            }
            con.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
    }
}
```

At this example I don't know the purpose of `con.setAutoCommit(true)` (1) at `finally` block because every task have already been committed from `try` block though it may occur an exception or not. May anyone give me a clearly explanation when shall use (1)? Thanks for help so much.

If the default method is `true`, so I just simply to do a `commit()` instead of (1) for ending a transaction block and the next block method (no need to manage the transaction for this block) will be become to default mode (1) and I don't need to set it to true again?

I have a hypothesis that `con.commit()` is just commit the statement and it still locks some row/table before (1) will be called again. I think I'm misunderstanding the `commit()` will automatically set the currently default become to `true` instead of trying to call (1) again because I've test some code, after calling `commit()` all locks from row/table will be released all, so my hypothesis is wrong too.

Comment: If you set it to `true` every statement is its own transaction. This somewhat defeats the purpose of an ACID compliant RDBMS. In this example, the programmer wants all the queries to succeed or neither - this is the A in ACID - atomicity. In short, `autoCommit` should **never** be `true` in a real application - it's only intended for toy/noddy use cases.

Comment: (although this example seems to be rather ill conceived as the two updates update the same row of the same table)

Comment: Hm, I've search on Oracle doc they said that "The statement con.setAutoCommit(true); enables auto-commit mode, which means that each statement is once again committed automatically when it is completed. Then, you are back to the default state where you do not have to call the method commit yourself..." which means if I use `commit()` or `rollback()`, the trans will be completed and I don't need `setAutoCommit(true)` (1) anymore because it is default state, right?  I just doubt when shall use (1) or it is old support and commit() is newer which can replace (1) or I've misunderstood something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you showed us, the code turns off autocommit and then turns it on at the end.  While autocommit is off, it repeatedly executes two updates at a time with a commit after each pair of updates.

In the example, the purpose for turning autocommit off at the end should be clear.  The programmer (presumably!) wants to execute pairs of updates with a commit between them *because* the pair of updates *need* to be done atomically.  If you don't turn off autocommit, you can't do this.

The purpose of turning autocommit back on in the `finally` block is to return it to its default state.  This presumably is done to allow the connection to be used again.  However, it is debatable that this is necessary:

- It costs almost nothing to turn autocommit off or on.
- There is no harm in calling `setAutoCommit(false)` if the connection already has autocommit turned off.

To my mind, the consequences of the above are that there are two sensible ways to deal with this:

- If the entire application needs explicit transactions, turn off autocommit when you establish the connection .... and leave it off.
- If different parts of the application have different autocommit requirement, then the simplest approach is for the code managing each transaction to set autocommit to what it needs, then *not bother* resetting it.

The 5 or so lines of extra code to restore the default autocommit state in a `finally` block don't strike me as necessary.  Indeed, unless you can ensure that the autocommit state is always restored, you are better of assuming that the state is uncertain; e.g. at the start of the `updateCoffeeSales` method ... or at the start of some other method that wants autocommit enabled.

Comment: Yeah I think the `finally` block is not necessary. Because 
I've search on Oracle doc they said that "if the transactions is rollbacked or committed, the transaction will end" so the default state will return to `true` and no need to call `setAutoCommit(true)` anymore, right? I just doubt when shall use (1) or it is old support and `commit()` is newer which can replace (1) or I've misunderstood something?

Comment: @mmo2112 nothing to do with "old" or "new" support - to do with the fundamentals of [SQL and transactional databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocommit).

Comment: @Boris the Spider, I just wonder about exact usage of 2 statement cause both of them are meaning final commit to end 1 transaction. They must have something different and I'm not sure about it. By the way, I can replace each other and the code still run well...